# How can I use Regex to remove the newline between these tags?

Tags: regex

I did see another solution on SO but it made the entire file with no new lines. I only need a particular section with no new lines.

I am attempting to remove the spacing between these tags so that they are right right next to one another such as this:

```
<a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href=""><img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338"></a><a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href=""><img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338"></a><a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href=""><img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338"></a><a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href=""><img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338"></a>
```

They currently looks like this:

```
                          <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
                              <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
                              <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
                              <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
```

Comment: try `[\r\n|\r|\n]` to find line breaks, you might need the `g`  flag though to get them all

Comment: Side note: if this is all the parsing you are doing then RegEx is fine but if you are doing more than just this you might want to look at other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the suggested regex I put in the comments, I added `\t` & `\s{2,}` to pull out tab characters and 2 or more white space characters.

```js
let temp = `<a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
                              <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
                              <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>
                              <a rel="nofollow noopener" style="display:inline; text-decoration: none;" href="">
                                <img border="0" class="full" height="auto" width="300" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x338">
                              </a>`;


console.log(temp.replace(/[\r\n|\r|\n|\t]/g, '').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' '))
```

Comment: Your pattern can interfere with the contents of tags though. Potentially changing something like this `<a rel="first          last" ....>` to `<a rel="firstlast".....>` unintentionally. It's better to restrict it to the outside of the tags.

Comment: for some reason the multiple spaces between "first" and "last" aren't showing, but it's there.

Comment: @emsimpson92 You are correct which is why I put it as an additional call so it would be easy to pull out.

Comment: @emsimpson92 Also it replaces multiple spaces with a single space so in the instance of `first_last` nothing will happen and in the case of `first_______last` it will end up being `first_last` which should be fine for most cases.

Comment: Yes, in most cases it is fine. I just wanted to point it out in case that was something OP would need.

Comment: @emsimpson92 In a not rude/condescending way, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work: `(?<=>)\s*|\s*(?=<a)`

You can see a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dT6trL/1). Just replace the match with `""`